# not letting me insert values with a where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause, mariadb

I'm making forums and I'm trying to make it so when you reply to a topic it will put the reply information in a table (**WHICH WORKS**) and then it will INSERT values into the subcategories table WHERE the subcategories ID is equal to this subcategories ID.

CODE:

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO subcategories (last_topic_title, last_topic_date, last_topic_user) VALUES (:last_topic_title, :last_topic_date, :last_topic_user) WHERE cid='".$cid."' AND sid='".$sid."'";
        $query_params = array(':last_topic_title' => $topic_title, ':last_topic_date' => $reply_date, ':last_topic_user' => $reply_creator);
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query" . $ex->getMessage());
        }
```

PROBLEM:

Its not letting me insert values with a WHERE clause. How can I get past this?

Comment: Where are `$cid` and `$sid` defined, and why are they not in your parameters array?

Comment: use `update` instead of `insert`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't because `INSERT` statements don't have `WHERE` clauses. You need to use an `UPDATE` statement.

For more information on these two seperate and different functions, consult:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html